# Coding and adding an RNG to dieharder for testing

Tags: c, random

I've been coding this RNG

```
#include <dieharder/libdieharder.h>

static unsigned long int tent3_get (void *vstate);
static double tent3_get_double (void *vstate);
static void tent3_set (void *vstate, unsigned long int s);

typedef struct {
  double seed;
} tent3_state_t;


static unsigned long int tent3_get (void *vstate)
{
   double nextx = seed;
   double current = nextx;
   if(current <= 1.0/3.0){
     nextx = 3.0 * current;
   }else if(current <= 2.0/3.0){
     nextx = 3.0 * current - 1.0;
   }else if(current <= 1.0){
     nextx = 3.0 * current - 2.0;
   }
}

static double tent3_get_double (void *vstate)
{
  return (double) tent3_get (vstate) / (double) UINT_MAX;
}

static void tent3_set (void *vstate, unsigned long int s)
{
  seed = s/UINT_MAX;
}

static const gsl_rng_type tent3_type =
{"Modified Tent Map",           /* name */
 UINT_MAX,          /* RAND_MAX */
 0,             /* RAND_MIN */
 sizeof (tent3_state_t),
 &tent3_set,
 &tent3_get,
 &tent3_get_double};

const gsl_rng_type *gsl_rng_tent3 = &tent3_type;
```

Then I added this RNG to the dieharder folder, libdieharder.
Next, I did the install process for dieharder.
When I ran the make command, I received a linker error. I've tried messing around with makefiles, but I'm not sure if that is the correct approach either.

I'm wondering if anyone has gotten dieharder to test an RNG they've made before, and whether or not I am on the right track?
Any and all advice/help is more than welcome as I am feeling very lost.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this even compile? Where is the return value from `tent3_get()`?

Comment: What are the linking errors you get?

Comment: And how did you install the dieharder code? I'm trying it right now, and struggling (successfully) with some code issues in it.

Comment: I changed the make files, and any file in the libdeiharder library that I had to in order to have an instance of it. Error:"Makefile:532: .deps/libdieharder_la-rng_tent3stry.Plo: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `.deps/libdieharder_la-rng_tent3stry.Plo'. " Thank you for the responses. As far as does it compile or work, I'm not sure because I haven't gotten it integrated with dieharder yet.

Comment: After solving that, I got the linker error that I originally made this post for. Error: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libdieharder.la] Error 1
make: *** [libwulf.time] Error 2"

Comment: I'm not sure that it is meant to link in your own code. The main usage seems to be that you input your random numbers via stdin to the dieharder program. I could be wrong.

Comment: I ended up finding out that my command for running the library was incorrect and I was being silly. Thank you for trying to help, I greatly appreciate it.